# Is it possible to save credentials in MAP toolkit?

Tags: windows, credentials

is this possible to save different credentials (both local and domain users) in MAP toolkit to avoid entering them every time the scan is performed?

Perhaps, the files with server names can have username and password (to be used for inventory) specified and processed by MAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1643.microsoft-assessment-and-planning-toolkit-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx#Q24) article on technet MAP doesn't save credentials for security reasons.

**Q:** `What does the MAP Toolkit do with administrative credentials used to collect inventory?`

**A:** 
**MAP never persists security credentials to disk.** The credentials you provide are encrypted using the DPAPI  and maintained only in memory. Credentials in memory are disposed of when the inventory completes. For each machine that MAP attempts to connect to, the credentials are passed to the connection method being used, at which point the credentials are securely handled by the remote operating system that is being interrogated. Credentials are never logged or written to the database or any other file.